# Running MAME on Wine MacOS keeps crashing after a bit of time

Tags: macos, wine, mame

When I'm playing MAME on my Macbook Pro (2013), it works almost perfectly, but after a random amount of time it just freezes. I've tried going into Settings to make it work, but I just can't find a fix. I have Wine Stable installed, running Sierra. This might just be a problem with RAM overload, but I'm still wondering how to fix this.

Comment: Which version of Wine are you using? The latest stable release is quite old; a new stable release will be coming out in the next 1-3 months since we've entered release candidate mode for Wine 5.0

Comment: @AndrewFan I’ve got 4.0.3 running. Should I switch to a dev build?

Comment: Given Wine's current release cycle and the fact that they're currently doing release candidates, I'd wait a few days (Dec 27?) for Wine 5.0-rc3 to come out if you want to try dev releases. Until Wine 5.0 is released, they will release a new version with bug fixes every week. There's no guarantee that your problem will be fixed, but now's probably the best time to report performance bugs to Wine so that they can be addressed before 5.0 hits.